# How can I Solve " loading page" error with VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html

When I Start debugging (F5) my website this error Occured:

"Firefox can't find the server at www.localhost.com."

I tried with IE but this error repeated.

How can I solve this problem?

thanks for ur attentions.

Comment: Don't try www.localhost.com, just try http://localhost/

Comment: Sorry, just remembered that Firefox always adds 'www.' and '.com' if it can't resolve the host, doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if WebDev.WebServer.exe is running(usually there will be an icon in notification area).

If it is running you can try http://127.0.0.1:2409/home/Default.aspx .

If above link works, you can edit the file (Windows)\System32\divers\etc\host and add a line:

127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: :thanks it works but there isn't host file at "(Windows)\System32\divers\etc\" location :S

Answer (score 1):

If You Want To Save '127.0.0.1 localhost' On (Windows)\System32\divers\etc\hosts Never Forget To Set The "Allow" Permission For The 'Hosts' File ...(win 7) . 
it Was My Problem And Fixed By The Changes mentioned !